# Remove url with specific word from bunch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie of Jquery. I want to remove all the url's which has g1 in them. how do I achieve this with Jquery?

**this is code**

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/";
var links = [];

//GET ALL LINKS
$html.find('.title h2 a').each(function(i, obj) {
    var link = app.makeLink(url, $(this).attr('href'));
    if (link != null) {
        links.push(link);
    }
});
```

**this is result (in array):**

```
www.example.com/g1/a
www.example.com/c1/b
www.example.com/g1/c
www.example.com/c1/d
www.example.com/c1/e
www.example.com/g1/f
www.example.com/g1/g
www.example.com/g1/h
www.example.com/c1/i
www.example.com/g1/j
```

Comment: Remove the URLs from where? Is this an array? Show some code, please.

Comment: Where are these urls?

Comment: Are these strings in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript function `String.indexOf`. With it you can seach for substrings in a string. If the substring is not present -1 is returned.

```
$html.find('.title h2 a').each(function(i, obj) {
    var link = app.makeLink(url, $(this).attr('href'));
    if (link != null && link.indexOf("g1") == -1) {
        links.push(link);
    }
});
```